# How to change the HTML type of a column using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

There is 3 issues in my code:

1. Infinite while loop I dont understand why, I'm just trying to test if the prompt is a number or not (If not -> Prompt again until it is) [SOLVED]
2. If min/max are correct, they should be added to all the cells from that column

From :
`<input type=text...`

To :
`<input type=number min=... max=...`

Currently, they are not even added and the type is indeed converted to number but for the full table, not for that specific column, which is not what I want obviously
What I want is to, when I press that "nbr" button from that specific column, convert all the cells' type from that column from text to nbr (and add min and max values to it) [SOLVED]

3. When I press that "nbr" button, it changes all the input fields from all the tables from text fields into number fields. What I'm trying to do is only changing the text fields from that column into "nbr" fields, only that column. [SOLVED]

This is the part that doesn't work as intended :

```js
//change column type to number
  $('body').on('click', '.nbr-col', function(event) {
    // ...
    // Here I'm trying to add the min attribute to all the number fields from that specific column
    $('input[type=\'number\']', event.delegateTarget).prop('min',($('#min').val()));

    // Here I'm trying to add the max attribute to all the number fields from that specific column
    $('input[type=\'number\']', event.delegateTarget).prop('max',($('#max').val()));

    // Here I'm trying to convert all the text fields to number fields for that specific column (it kinda works, but it converts all the text fields from all the table to number fields, that's not what I want to do
    $('input', event.delegateTarget).prop('type','number');
  });
```

So the result should be (for example) :

- Create as much columns and rows as I want
- Press the "nbr" button from column 2
- Should convert all the text fields from column 2 into number fields :

Convert this :

```html
<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
```

To this :

```html
<td><input type='number' min=value_from_prompt max=value_from_prompt class="form-control"></td>
```

For each cells from column 2

Here is a picture :
[nbr press converting all the  into "number" from all the table, not only the column in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oMNU.png)

Here's a full code fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wh9y05qt/

Here's my full code snippet :

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {
  // add row
  $('body').on('click', '.add-row', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('.table-content').find('.table tbody tr:last');
    if (tr.length > 0) {
      var clone = tr.clone();
      clone.find(':text').val('');
      tr.after(clone);
    } else {
      var cols = $(this).closest('.table-content').find('th').length,
        tr0 = $('<tr/>');
      tr0.html('<td><span class="remove remove-row">x</span></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control"> </td>');
      for (var i = 2; i < cols; i++) {
        tr0.append('<td> static element </td>')
      }
      $(this).closest('.table-content').find('.table tbody').append(tr0);
      //$(this).closest('.table-content').find('.table tbody').append('<tr> <td><span class="remove remove-row">x</span></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control"> </td><td> static element </td><td> static element </td></tr>');
    }
  });

  // delete row
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });

  // add column
  $('body').on('click', '.add-col', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append('<th><input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" value=""> <span class="pull-left remove remove-col">x</span> <span class="pull-left text text-col">text</span> <span class="pull-left nbr nbr-col">nbr</span> </th>');
    $(this).parent().find('.table tbody tr').append('<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>');
  });
  
  // change column type to text
  $('body').on('click', '.text-col', function(event) {
    // Get index of parent TD among its siblings (add one for nth-child)
    //var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    // Find all TD elements with the same index
    $('input', event.delegateTarget).prop('type','text');
  });
  
  // change column type to number
  $('body').on('click', '.nbr-col', function(event) {
   // Get index of parent TD among its siblings (add one for nth-child)
    //var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    // Find all TD elements with the same index
    var filter = /^[0-9]*$/g;
    var cond = false;
    var min = prompt('Valeur minimum :');
    while (cond == false)
    {
     if (min.match(filter))
      {
       cond = true;
      }
      else {
       var min = prompt('Valeur minimum incorrect, réessayez :');
      }
    }
    
    var cond = false;
    var max = prompt('Valeur maximum :');
    while (cond == false)
    {
     if (max.match(filter))
      {
       cond = true;
      }
      else {
       var max = prompt('Valeur maximum incorrect, réessayez :');
      }
    }
    $('input[type=\'number\']', event.delegateTarget).prop('min',($('#min').val()));
    $('input[type=\'number\']', event.delegateTarget).prop('max',($('#max').val()));
    $('input', event.delegateTarget).prop('type','number');
  });


  // remove column
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-col', function(event) {
    // Get index of parent TD among its siblings (add one for nth-child)
    var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    // Find all TD elements with the same index
    $('th', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');
    $('td', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.remove {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: red;
}
.remove:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: blue;
}
.text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nbr {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: green;
}
.nbr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form-control {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="table-content">
      <button class="btn btn-link add-col">Add Column</button>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Define</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="remove remove-row">x</span></td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-link add-row">Add row</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are comparing a string against a regex object `if (min == filter)` so you are getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: Or you can use `min.match(filter)`

Comment: Thank you guys, that does solve my problem 1)
I'm dumb

Comment: I'm basically trying to add this : 
<input type="number" min="$('#min')" max="$('#max')">

Comment: I'm trying to select a full column from my table and convert the text type into number type (and I'm trying to insert the min and max attributes too)
Here a picture : https://i.imgur.com/J1KtNlC.png
This is what I want to do, but only for the column in question, not the full table (check the screen in my original post to understand what I mean)
Again, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Alright, no worries, I will edit it completly with screens to show what I'm trying to explain and with the relevant code all in the same place, either later today or tomorrow, thank you for your replies by the way !
Sorry for the inconvenience, as you can see, I'm indeed new to this site, and my english is not that great, I'll try my best to make better posts from now on ! :)

Comment: @CalvinNunes I edited everything, I hope this will help, if not I can try to do better ! :) Thank you in advance, have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this long question, that what you really want is to just select all inputs from second `td` of the table body and set `min`, `max` and `type="number"`, if is this, then I think that what you need is:

```
$(".table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) input")
```

check below snippet, is it what you need?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add row
  $('body').on('click', '.add-row', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parents('.table-content').find('.table tbody tr:last');
    if (tr.length > 0) {
      var clone = tr.clone();
      clone.find(':text').val('');
      tr.after(clone);
    } else {
      var cols = $(this).closest('.table-content').find('th').length,
        tr0 = $('<tr/>');
      tr0.html('<td><span class="remove remove-row">x</span></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control"> </td>');
      for (var i = 2; i < cols; i++) {
        tr0.append('<td> static element </td>')
      }
      $(this).closest('.table-content').find('.table tbody').append(tr0);
    }
  });

  // delete row
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });

  // add column
  $('body').on('click', '.add-col', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append('<th><input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" value=""> <span class="pull-left remove remove-col">x</span> <span class="pull-left text text-col">text</span> <span class="pull-left nbr nbr-col">nbr</span> </th>');
    $(this).parent().find('.table tbody tr').append('<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>');
  });

  // change column type to text
  $('body').on('click', '.text-col', function(event) {
    $('input', event.delegateTarget).prop('type', 'text');
  });

  // change column type to number
  $('body').on('click', '.nbr-col', function(event) {
    var filter = /^[0-9]*$/g;
    var cond = false;
    var min = prompt('Valeur minimum :');
    while (cond == false) {
      if (min.match(filter)) {
        cond = true;
      } else {
        var min = prompt('Valeur minimum incorrect, réessayez :');
      }
    }

    var cond = false;
    var max = prompt('Valeur maximum :');
    while (cond == false) {
      if (max.match(filter)) {
        cond = true;
      } else {
        var max = prompt('Valeur maximum incorrect, réessayez :');
      }
    }
    let colToModify = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    let inputsCol = $(".table tbody tr td:nth-child(" + colToModify + ") input")
    inputsCol.attr("type", "number").prop("min", min).prop("max", max)
    console.log("modified columns index: " + colToModify)
  });

  // remove column
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-col', function(event) {
    var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $('th', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');
    $('td', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.remove {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.remove:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: blue;
}

.text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nbr {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: green;
}

.nbr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-content">
  <button class="btn btn-link add-col">Add Column</button>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Define</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="remove remove-row">x</span></td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-link add-row">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is almost what I want but I want each "nbr" button to convert its column types from text to number


Like for example if you press "nbr" from column 4, it should convert all the column types from column 4 from text to number (and add min max values to it)

Comment: THANKS A LOT !!

I just changed a little bit the code so it matches the column
Like this :
```javascript
let ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    let inputsCol2 = $('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + ndx + ') input')
    inputsCol2.attr("type", "number").prop("min", min).prop("max", max)
```

Comment: yes, I was just edditing this to show the solution, but you already found out.

Comment: Let me give you a tip: You code is a little bit messy, avoid writing HTML as string to append, this removes you a lot of ability to manipulate elements, you could for example add a `data-index` to the element "nbr", that way you could just select all columns using this `data` attribute, but you can't because you write HTML as string. Take a look about: `document.createElement()` it's very useful and you'll have all control over created element before appending it